# To add address edit link in existing shipping address in Magento 2 Checkout page

Tags: magento2.3, onepage-checkout, shipping-address, php-7.2

How to add an address edit link besides default feature,**Edit** link in Shipping Address in Magento 2 Checkout Page if there are multiple shipping addresses with default. That address edit link would go to customer's address edit page like https://domain_name/customer/address/edit/id/address_id/. It has been tried by adding the code, `<a class="action edit-address-link" attr="'href': 'magento2_domain_name/customer/address/edit/id/' + address().id" data-bind="text: 'Edit Address'"></a><br/>` in Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html. But address().id shows undefined. I can't understand how to solve it properly.

[image]

And if it has been used the default **Edit** link and by clicking **Edit** link, it shows a  popup box, but its fields values like company name, phone number have been shown blank. And also keeps the only default value in city, state, country fields in multiple shipping address edit pop up box.

If any one knows that particular requirement or there is any clue on to fulfil this requirement, please reply it as soon as possible.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try the code like this one :

```
<a class="action edit-address-link" attr="'href': 'magento2_domain_name/customer/address/edit/id/' + address().address_id" data-bind="text: 'Edit Address'"></a><br/>
```

Comment: Sorry Dear, this one is not working. It shows same, undefined means "https://domain_name/customer/address/edit/id/undefined" instead of "https://domain_name/customer/address/edit/id/2"

Answer (score 0):

Try the code like this one :

Replace address_id to customerAddressId then you can check it. I have tested.